# Difficulties in Sage One integration with Django (Python)

Tags: python, django, sage-one

I have developed an one page application using AngularJs and Django(Python). I want to integrate Sage One Application with my application for accounting purpose(country US).

I have gone through so many links and blogs in google and what I have found that all the libraries are written in PHP, Ruby and some other language. And I could not find any solution.
This is the link I followed : https://developer.columbus.sage.com/docs#/us/sageone/core/gs-welcome

Then I found another link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sageone-api-client/0.0.2 for the integration with Python. And here, We need an API Key. I tried to get the API Key by following their instructions. But after asending some email and all still they are asking me to provide some company information and all. And i just lost the process. So Can any one tell whether I am following the right way ? Or I have to build some code as it was written in their PHP Example? Is there any way to get the API key for development purpose?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should change the title into a question ;-)

Before answering in more detail, let me tell you that the Python client you found is for the South African Sage One and won't help you connecting to Sage One US. You probably will have to implement your own client lib for Python.

Comment: Except for the requirement to add a HMAC signature it looks like a very standard Rest/json API with oauth2 auth, so writing your own client using python-requests and requests-oauthlib should be quite easy.